# Amazon Web Service Usage Cost through Command Line

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, boto, billing

I am working on Amazon Web Service (EC2, S3) to set up an instances given the following detail on the account. (I don't have administrative rights to the Amazon account through the web browser)

1. Amazon Account Number
2. Access Key ID
3. Secret Access Key

Do anyone know how can I check the total usage cost spent through command line interface? I wouldn't want to give the owner a surprise of how much Amazon have charged him at the end of the month.

**P.S.:** To date of writing Amazon does not provide account charges information through the command line or API (According to @[Eric Hammond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111286/eric-hammond)). If Amazon does in the later date, please give me a head up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon AWS does not currently provide account charges information through the command line or API.

Accrued account charges can be viewed through a login on the AWS web site:

> http://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary